# Detecting onClick in recycler view using data binding in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

1. I am Referring to [vogella-tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html) for databinding
2. **What i am trying to do**: What is the best way to detect onClick in recycler view row for each Item using the dataBinding

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="temp"
            type="com.vogella.android.databinding.TemperatureData" />
        <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="com.vogella.android.databinding.MainActivityPresenter"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</layout>
```

---

**rowlayout.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="obj"
            type="com.vogella.android.databinding.TemperatureData"
            />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_listentry"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="@{obj.location}"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@{obj.celsius}"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

---

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private List<TemperatureData> data;

        // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
        // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
        // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                // each data item is just a string in this case
                private final ViewDataBinding binding;

                public MyViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
                        super(binding.getRoot());
                        this.binding = binding;
                }
                public void bind(Object obj) {
                       binding.setVariable(BR.obj,obj);
                       binding.executePendingBindings();
                }
        }

        // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
        public MyAdapter(List<TemperatureData> myDataset) {
                data = myDataset;
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                // create a new view
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
                // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
                return new MyViewHolder(binding);
        }

        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                final TemperatureData temperatureData = data.get(position);
                holder.bind(temperatureData);

        }

        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

}
```

---

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends MyBaseAdapter {

    List<TemperatureData> data;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<TemperatureData> myDataset) {
        data = myDataset;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getDataAtPosition(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutIdForType(int viewType) {
        return R.layout.rowlayout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if you have already found a solution, but I managed to do it quite easily.

1) modify `onCreateViewHolder` method to look like this:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    MainActivityPresenter presenter = new MainActivityPresenter(this, parent.getContext());
    binding.setVariable(BR.presenter,presenter);

    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    return new MyViewHolder(binding);
}
```

2) make MyAdapter to implement `MainActivityContract.View` so in the end it looks like following:

`public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements MainActivityContract.View`

3) Implement necessary methods within `MyAdapter`; e.g:

```
@Override
public void showData(TemperatureData data) {
    String clickedItemCelsius = data.getCelsius();
}
```

4) Add Presenter variable to your row layout file:

```
    <variable
        name="presenter"
        type="com.mvvm.ViewModels.MainActivityPresenter"/>
```

5) Finally hook your `onClick` event under RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onShowData(obj)}"
    >
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is MainActivityPresenter??

Comment: This is a good way to make a memory leak, viewHolder should be kept as lightweight as possible because it'll be recreated as user scrolls.
Should just pass in the onClickListener in the constructor of the viewholder

Comment: What is MainActivityPresenter? Please provide more explanation

Answer (score 2):

our viewModel used in recycler view

```
class UserViewModel (val name: String?, val onClick: () -> Unit)
```

layout for user_item.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="...model.UserViewModel" />
</data>

         <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="@{()->model.onClick.invoke()}"
                android:text="@{model.name}" />
<merge>
```

creating of models in presenter or modelView or somewhere else

```
fun loadData() {
   // ..
        val user = UserViewModel("name") { handleUserEvent() }

   .. //
 }

fun handleUserEvent() {
   // TODO handle on click
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most common solution would be to put a click listener on the row layout's root view and call a method on your view model.
For example in rowlayout.xml:

```
...
<RelativeLayout
    android:onClick="@{() -> obj.performClickAction()}"
....
```

Comment: Yes, I typically handle it that way. Your issue is more of a debugging one then, this should work. Try setting clickable=true on the RelativeLayout, other than that it's just a matter of debugging to find what isn't getting called.

Comment: I think its not working in listView ... works in simple views

Answer (score 1):

Hey I read that article about a week ago and had the same problem! The article barely mentions how actions should be handled but there is [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#event_handling) on how to do it. In short, you are going to want a `handler`.

This handler is defined in your xml

```
<data>
    ...
    <variable name="handlers" type="com.example.MyHandlers"/>
    ...
</data>
```

example usage

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@{user.firstName}"
       android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickFriend}"/>
```

The MyHandlers.java would look like this

```
public class MyHandlers {
    public void onClickFriend(View view) { ... }
}
```

You would change the add one more line to your `MyAdapter.java`

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  public void bind(Object obj) {
                   binding.setVariable(BR.obj,obj);
                   binding.executePendingBindings();
                   binding.setHandlers(new MyHandlers());
            }
```

I haven't tested this code but if this doesn't work I can share my adapter .

Comment: Where should I define  `public class MyHandlers {
    public void onClickFriend(View view) { ... }
}` .... Is it inside Presenter(ViewModel) .... because i need to perform some action in view model based on the item click

Comment: Also I am not able to set Handlers

Comment: Why can you not add handlers? Check what the variable name is. The example I wrote has the name handlers

Comment: @Devrath Just build the project

Answer (score 1):

If other suggestions don't seem to work the way you think it should, take a look at Google Codelab training, specifically "[Interacting with RecyclerView items](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interacting-with-items/index.html)". It's a part of series, but if you are interested in handling the click event in RecyclerView (with Data Binding), you just need to read the aforementioned chapter only.

In short, 1) create a listener class with `onClick()`, 2) add listener class as data in list item's xml layout file, and 3) use `android:onClick="{...}"` to map the list item's click event to the listener.

I'm sure there are other ways to achieve the same goal, but this approach seems fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

This way we can use the item click on databinding

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomView> {


    List<NewsModel> newsList;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public CustomAdapter(List<NewsModel> newsList)
    {
        this.newsList = newsList;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomView onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {


        if(layoutInflater == null)
        {
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        }

        final NewsBinding newsBinding  = NewsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,parent,false);

        newsBinding.setPresenter(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onclickListener() {

                Log.d("click me ","click me "+newsBinding.getNewsview().Title);
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),""+newsBinding.getNewsview().Title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

      //  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.innerlayout,parent,false);
       return new CustomView(newsBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomView holder, int position) {

      //  News news = newsList.get(position);
       // holder.title.setText(news.getTitle());
       // holder.desc.setText(news.getDesc());

        NewsModel newsModel = newsList.get(position);
        holder.bind(newsModel);




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsList.size();
    }

    public class CustomView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private NewsBinding newsBinding;
       // TextView title, desc;
        public CustomView(NewsBinding newsBinding) {
            super(newsBinding.getRoot());

            this.newsBinding = newsBinding;
            //title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleval);
            //desc =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.descval);

        }

        public void bind(NewsModel newsModel)
        {
            this.newsBinding.setNewsview(newsModel);
        }

        public NewsBinding getNewsBinding()
        {
            return newsBinding;
        }

    }
}
```

complete project is https://github.com/Vishulucky/DataBinding-MVVM.git

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyAdapter() :
   RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {



      inner class MyViewHolder(private val binding: ItemMyListBinding) :
           RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {


             fun bind(yourItem: YourItem) {
                 binding.setVariable(BR.item, yourItem)
                 binding.executePendingBindings()
                 binding.animeListCard.setOnClickListener {
                                onItemClickListener?.let { click ->
                    click(yourItem)
                }

            }
        }


        }

  
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        val binding: ItemMyListBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            R.layout.item_My_list,
            parent,
            false
        )

            return  MyViewHolder(binding)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {


       holder.bind(getItem(position))


    }

    
    //add these  
    private var onItemClickListener: (( YourItem) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: ( YourItem) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }


}
```

R.layout.item_My_list layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.temp.example.data.MyItem" />

    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{item.title}"
              />    


  

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

then in your activity :

```
myAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { item->
         
           //your code here 
           
       }
```